# Excel Help: Fill Tool - Drag to the side (across columns) but increase the formula by Row Number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

There are answers out there to this question, but all of them have been under explianed so hence to difficult to coprehend and use them to my advantage.

I want to do the seemingly simple (but not) task of Draging a Formula (Filling a series) across Column's while increasing the formula row number relativley.

For Example to drag this formula:

| =A1 | =A2 | =A3

Some other notes, Transposing by copy paste has proven too difficult for the amount of data.

Offset and Indirect has been used by other people to do this but I don't get how they work at all so when I attempt to use them I don't know how to format it to my range.

Here's a example photo

Idealy we want the dragged section to continue on to fill the formula.
[image: Column to Row 2]

Comment: I don't think this is possible by dragging. Transposing usually works quite well in my experience. Can you expand upon the problems you have with the size of your data with the transpose method?

Comment: my data is about 400 down and 400 across and what you see here i sa very basic question so I can incorporate an if statement the formula but you need not worry about that. I know the transpose method may seem the easiest but... it's not very good with changing the formulas once you've transposed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offset is the simpliest solution.

> `=OFFSET($A$1,COLUMN()-1,)`

Step by step:

1. Choose B2 and write

   > `=offset(`
2. Hit left arrow and then F4

   > `$A$1` *It's like an ancor for the formula.*
3. Write

   > `,column()-1,)` *The second argument is number of rows we want to offset from ancor. Third is number of columns. We'll leave it empty.*
4. Fill all cells you need

   > *Sweet part is formula must be the same in all cells. So you can drag, copy and move it without fear.*

Comment: Works Like a Charm! Hope it can help others aswell who have had the same problem.